# Переход на профиль пользователя из списка пользователей

Tags: php

Начнем с того что я новенькой в этой сфере. У всех есть свой профиль, и перейти на них можно, как я знаю, добавив GET-запрос в url.Проблема заключается в том, что в приложенном коде ниже я вывожу список всех пользователей сайта, список и выводится, но на профиль пользователя не переходит, так как не открывает url. Возможно нужно подкорректировать *index.php* .Хочу понять, как можно исправить эту проблему.

**Код:**

*Фрагмент friend.php*

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users");
for ($array = []; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $array[] = $row);
foreach ($array as $elem) {
            echo "<a href='profile?id={$elem[id]}'>xuy ";
```

*Фрагмент index.php*

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/') $page = 'main';
else {
    
    $page = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
    if ( !preg_match('/^[A-z0-9]{3,15}$/', $page) ) exit(header("Location: /404notFound"));
}
if ( file_exists('general/all/'.$page.'.php') ) include 'general/all/'.$page.'.php';

else if ( $_SESSION['id'] == NULL and file_exists('general/guest/'.$page.'.php') ) include 'general/guest/'.$page.'.php';

else if ( $_SESSION['id'] == true and file_exists('general/authorized/'.$page.'.php') ) include 'general/authorized/'.$page.'.php';

else if ( $_SESSION['id'] == true and file_exists('general/admin/'.$page.'.php') ) include 'general/admin/'.$page.'.php';

else if ( $_SESSION['id'] == NULL) header("Location: /login");

else header("Location: /404notFound");
```

**Буду очень рад если мне кто-нибудь да поможет.**

Comment: суть вопроса то в чем, мы придумать должны фрагмент кода или что? передал ты `?id=xuy` дальше что? получить может надо где-то этот id в `$_GET['id']`? чего ты нам этот код с session показываешь, если он отношения к делу не имеет?

Comment: смотри, я вывел список с ссылкой /profile?id=$elem[id], в код с профилем я добавил переменную $id = $_GET['id'], но у меня все равно не получается перейти в профиль с определенным id, index.php я добавил, потому что мало ли там ошибка, я хочу, чтобы мне подсказали куда дальше двигаться

Answer (score 0):

**Спасибо всем кто помог с ответом**

Оказалось, нужно было исправить кое-что в *index.php*:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/') $page = 'main';
else {
    
    $page = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
    $lenght = strcspn($page, '?');
    $page = substr($page, 0, $lenght);
    
    if ( !preg_match('/^[A-z0-9]{3,15}$/', $page) ) exit(header("Location: /404notFound"));
}
```

Comment: Для вашего развития, я хотел бы порекомендовать изучить вопрос роутинга в современных php веб-приложениях. Вот человек, который всё понятно объясняет https://elisdn.ru/blog/114/psr7-framework-router

Comment: Не надо писать в заголовке вопроса "(Вопрос решен)", надо ответить и принять ответ зеленой галкой. Тогда всем будет понятно что на вопрос есть принятый ответ.

Comment: Списибо за совет!